# Debug objc_msgSend crash I cant reproduce

Tags: ios, multithreading, uialertview, segmentation-fault, objc-message-send

I've had some crash reports from bugsense for my iOS app I'm not able to reproduce and so not to debug. It happens more than 200 times a day so I guess it's quite serious.

I've read something about NSZombie but I'm not able to reproduce the crash so I guess it's useless.
Here is a crash report:

```
SIGSEGV
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3aa515b0 objc_msgSend + 15
1 UIKit 0x34d493df + 294
2 UIKit 0x34cae469 + 52
3 QuartzCore 0x34926099 + 160
4 QuartzCore 0x34925ff1 + 64
5 IOMobileFramebuffer 0x36ba1fd7 + 154
6 IOKit 0x33920449 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 192
7 CoreFoundation 0x32d035db + 118
8 CoreFoundation 0x32d0e173 + 34
9 CoreFoundation 0x32d0e117 + 138
10 CoreFoundation 0x32d0cf99 + 1384
11 CoreFoundation 0x32c7febd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
12 CoreFoundation 0x32c7fd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
13 GraphicsServices 0x368562eb GSEventRunModal + 74
14 UIKit 0x34b95301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
15 My Bet main (main.m:16) Live 0x000705e7 0x6d000 + 13799
```

On some similar threads they believe the problem can be in UIAlertView, so here is an example on how I use them:
in file.h

```
UIAlertView *alertView;
```

in file.m

```
-(void)wait{
UIActivityIndicatorView * activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityView.frame = CGRectMake(121.0f, 50.0f, 37.0f, 37.0f);
[activityView startAnimating];
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Searching...", @"") message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView addSubview:activityView];
[alertView show];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(function) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
-(void)function{
// Do some web request
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
if(response == nil){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Timeout", @"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection timeout", @"") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Close", @"") otherButtonTitles:nil ];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

Any hint on how I can procede to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the crash is due to dismissing and showing the `UIAlertView` from other thread.

Never do `UI` tasks in other threads. `UI` tasks should be done in Main Thread.

Change `function` like:

```
-(void)function
{
 // Do some web request

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    if(response == nil)
    {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Timeout", @"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection timeout", @"") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Close", @"") otherButtonTitles:nil ];
    [alert show];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: is it the same to do dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];}); and then use another dispatch_async to show the second alert?

Comment: @user1187692:P there is no need of doing this :) You have already in the main thread using `dispatch_get_main_queue`, then no need of again using GCD and `dispatch_get_main_queue`. You can write those lines in a single `dispatch_get_main_queue` GCD.